# Can't redirect user after login in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a problem with my dnn-site.(DNN v9.01.01)
I have an userpage/landingpage for logged in users and i want the user to be redirected there when they login.
but when login you always are moved/(redirected) to the startpage for the site.(the root startpage)

i have edit in. Redirect after login under security. -- Nothing happens.

i have edit in the databas hostsettings. (Redirect_AfterLogin). -- Nothing happens.

i dont know what to do or where to look to fix this issue.

is there someone that have a clue how to fix this?

/regards

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. DNN redirects after login to the page selected in the `Security > Redirect after login` setting. Are you using a custom login module or is there something on the landing page that is redirecting users? Tested in 9.2.2

Comment: No i am not using any custom module... i understand that its hard to reproduce this i just should work. :/  i dont really know where to start debug.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is an issue with DNN 9.1.1.  Try upgrading to 9.3.1, being mindful that you may hit some issues if your third-party modules haven't been upgraded.

Comment: i will do that. :) i will post the result here.. hope it solves the problem.